# Replace the words "can't, don't" by "can not, do not" using python

Tags: regex, python-2.7, nlp, nltk

I need to replace words like "{can't, don't, won't }"  by  "{can not, do not, would not}" using python

The problem is:
"can't" can be detected by checking suffix "n't", so we can replace "n't" by "not"
But how can we transform "ca" to "can" as when we split "can't" it should be transformed to "can not"?

Comment: I think you've got bigger problems than you've identified here. How do you plan on handling `won't` when the resulting first `will not` is drastically diferent (`wo -> will`). English is not an unambiguous language, and has few to no firm rules. rarely will any (feasibly simple) algorithm work for all cases. You may be better off using an approach involving a list of known contractions.

Comment: I need to search words in afinn dictionary for polarity checking  but words like "don't' does not exist so i need to break it. also i think transforming "won't to "would not" or "will not" is not going to make much difference in determing polarity

Comment: If your goal is to support polarity checking, just modify your dictionary to match the tokenization: E.g., add features "ca" and "wo" as variants of "can" and "will".

Comment: @CollinD I guess the question is clear enough according to the tags and is a genuine problem. Can we reopen this problem?
What he meant to ask is : 

in NLTK, words like :
{can't, don't, won't }  will be broken as {ca + not , do + not , wo + not }, where do + not makes sense but other two are wrong. So whats the workaround...

Comment: @PriyankPathak I don't feel that this question should be reopened so I won't be casting a vote. The close reason might not be perfect, but the post still lacks any indication that any significant work had been put into this question before posting it here. It's one of thousands of questions daily that deserves the "SO is not a codewriting service" answer. I think if you have a similar issue and can write it up as a high quality question, you should definitely do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the rules of English are large and sometimes inconsistent, your best bet is probably just to set up full word maps rather than trying to figure out on the fly which letters are represented by the apostrophe.

In other words, a dictionary with values like:

```
can't    -> can not
don't    -> do not
won't    -> will not
:
oughtn't -> ought not
```

Comment: And the infamous, `y'all'd'n't've`